# Why is my text below the element?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make responsive design with CSS. Everything works great, with one problem: I can not put few divs with text in the needed location. It is hard to understand what I mean, so [here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73JJ8/).

As you see a text `Filename Some descr` is shown in the bottom and I want it to appear inside of the ligth-grey box.

```
<div class="OD-grid">
    <span class="OD-template">
        <span class="OD-template-folder">Folder</span>
    </span>
    <span class="OD-template">
        <span class="OD-template-file">
            <img src="public/img/image.png"/>
            <span class="OD-template-info">
                <div> Filename</div>
                <div> Some descr</div>
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>


.OD-grid > .OD-template{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 90px;
    width: 33.333333%;            // this should be responsive. 50%, 25%, 33.33333%
}

.OD-template-folder{
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #9FB9CA;
    padding: 10px 0 0 10px;
    background: #0072c6;
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.OD-template-file {
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #eaecee;
}

.OD-template-file > img{
    padding: 16px;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    background: #b1b1b1;
}
```

in such a way that if I change the line before `// this should be responsive. 50%, 25%, 33.33333%` to any of these numbers, it should work properly.

Comment: Why would you like to put a block object in an inline object? You shouldn't use <div> in <span> tags, your page won't validate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the `.OD-template-info` class the style display:`inline-block` This shall make the text go inside the light grey area

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73JJ8/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `float: left` style to `.OD-template-file > img` and .`OD-template-file > .OD-template-info`.

Answer (score 1):

I dont now how did you decide to use that labels in that way, but you could add `float:left;` to `.OD-template-file > img`

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/73JJ8/5/)

I used `inline-table` and `table`displays so that their widths are relative to its content.
Having `vertical-align:top` makes the text align to top, similar to the other ones.

```
.OD-template-info {
    display: inline-table;    
    vertical-align: top;
}

.OD-template-info > * {
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: No idea why someone downvoted this. It looks correct.